# how to get image clientHeight an image?

Tags: javascript

I have this problem: i am trying to get the height of few images inside a div but i'm having problems

here's my code:

//HTML

```
<div id="album-grid" class="clearfix">
<div class="item">
<div class="imgs"><img src="img/1.jpg"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

//javascript

```
var img = document.getElementByTagName('img'); 

var height = img.clientHeight;

$(".TestDiv").css('height', height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

This statements returns multiple object i.e. collection of object. You can't use it like this

```
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

use `img[0]` to fetch the first object and for all objects you can iterate over `img` variable.

**Update**: I just missed that you have put wrong function above. It is `document.getElementsByTagName` not `document.getElementByTagName` (remember the plural of elements)

Comment: please give me some insight so that i can understand what mistake have I made and you down voted this

Comment: It will still not work as `getElementsByTagName` is plural (and answer is almost identical to the one given already).

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware Thank a lot man, I just missed that completely but now I have updated it.